# Что написать, чтобы пользователь вводил интересующие для меня знаки, в обратном случае, программа просила бы заново ввести знак?

Tags: python-3.x, циклы, переменные

```
sign=input("Enter a sign: ")

while sign != "+" or sign != "-":

    sign = input("Enter a sign: ")

print("You entered + or -")
```

Comment: язык программирования хотя бы уточните с помощью метки (нажав [edit]).

Answer (score 1):

```
sign = input("Enter a sign: ")

while sign != "+" and sign != "-":

    sign = input("Enter a sign: ")

print("You entered + or -")
```

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Comment: Если у вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Если интересуют только плюс или минус, то можно написать так:

```
while True:
    sign = input("Enter a sign: ")

    if sign == "+" or sign == "-":
        break
    else:
        print("Re-enter")

print("U entered + or -")
```